# Ionic2/TypeScript clear variable after loop is complete

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do what I think is supposed to be a pretty simple example. This is written in Ionic 2 with typescript.

I want to loop through the 2 hello arrays. Once its done looping, I want to clear this.message. I have a runHello() function. I thought that the for loop would run first then run this.message ="" but instead it runs before the loop is complete.

I googled a lot about this and couldnt find much help other than Promises. I would think that would be a little complex for this and promises dont seem to work with either Ionic or Typescript.

I have a resetHello() function which I was going to bind to a button if I can't get this to work.

Fairly new to learning to program. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
export class Page1 {

  message: string = "";
  helloArr: Array<any>;

  constructor() {}

  sayHello(){
   setTimeout( ()=>{
      this.message ="Hello";
        }, 2000);
    };

  sayHello2(){
   setTimeout( ()=>{
      this.message ="Hello2";
    }, 3000);
  };

  runHello(){
    this.helloArr = [this.sayHello(), this.sayHello2()];

      for(let func of this.helloArr){
        func;
      };

      this.message = "this runs before for loop is done";

  }

  // resetHello(){
    //   this.message ="";
   // }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` calls are async, so you have to wait for their callbacks to run, before checking if `this.message` should be reset.

```
    export class Page1 {

        message: string = "";
        helloArr: Array < any > ;
        count = 0;
        constructor() {}

        sayHello() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.message = "Hello";
                decrement()
            }, 2000);
        };

        sayHello2() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.message = "Hello2";
                decrement();
            }, 3000);
        };

        runHello() {
            this.helloArr = [this.sayHello(), this.sayHello2()];
            this.count = this.helloArr.length;
            for (let func of this.helloArr) {
                func;
            };

            // this.message = "this runs before for loop is done";

        }
        decrement() {
            this.count = --this.count;
            if (this.count == 0) {
                this.message = "";
            }
        }

    }
```